# Run Umbraco 6.x in Medium Trust / Shared hosting environment

Tags: asp.net, configuration, umbraco, shared-hosting, medium-trust

I have a Umbraco 6.1.5 project, and i want to deploy it to a shared hosting environment. 
I read that Umbraco 6 can run in Medium Trust, but i cant find much more info than just that one sentence.

And, in the web.config i found this setting: umbracoUseMediumTrust which i can set to "true". But, after doing so, i get the following error:

*Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.*

Is there anyone who knows how to run Umbraco in such a Shared Hosting environment?

Comment: Questions like this are more suited for the Umbraco forum - http://our.umbraco.org/forum/ and there are plenty of discussions about this topic.

Comment: The Umbraco forum itself is pretty lame.. Just as it's documentation. So that is why i went to my very favourite forum, being this one, right here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I addition to setting `umbracoUseMediumTrust=true`, it should just be a matter of setting the `trust` and `machineKey` elements:

```
<system.web>
    <trust level="Medium" originUrl=".*" />
    <machineKey validationKey="yourKey"
                decryptionKey="yourKey"
                validation="SHA1"
                decryption="AES" />
    ....
</system.web>
```

You can generate a `validationKey` and `decryptionKey` here: http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey